# Profile Not Filling When Signing In With Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor, ecmascript-6

In my MeteorJs app you are allowed to sign in with Facebook when they sign in with facebook their profile is not automatically filled in.

```
addFacebookInformationToProfile() {
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      // This will only merge in information the first time, then ignore it once the flag is true
      const user = Meteor.user();
      let username = slugify(user.services.facebook.name, '');
      let i = 1;
      while (Meteor.users.findOne({username})) {
        username = slugify(user.services.facebook.name, '') + '' + i;
        i++;
      }
      Meteor.users.update({ _id: Meteor.userId(), 'profile.facebook': { $ne:true }}, {
        $set: {
          'profile.email': user.services.facebook.email,
          'profile.name': user.services.facebook.name,
          'username': username,
          'profile.gender': user.services.facebook.gender,
          'profile.picture': "https://graph.facebook.com/" + user.services.facebook.id + "/picture/?width=150&height=150",
          'profile.facebook': true
        }
      });
    }
  },
```

When I `console.log` the profile.picture line I get a url that when inputted in the browser it shows the Facebook user's profile picture.

For example: (http://graph.facebook.com/100004071683764/picture/?width=150&height=150)

This is how it shows in the actual app: (https://www.dropbox.com/s/6n1svdq56x6ctx8/Screenshot%202016-05-13%2017.24.06.png?dl=0)

How do I display the user's profile picture in the circle above instead of the gray box around the circle.

Background:

We are using imgix and s3 to take our data.

The app is hosted here relyphe.com

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 <img class="img-circle" >
```

This will make your profile picture appear in a circle.